# Call a vb subroutine from c# generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, subroutine

I have a legacy application in asp. Code behind is written in vb, which I am not much aware of. So I added a generic handler and call it from Ajax. Now I have a subroutine in code behind, which is called on page load. I want to call it again but either from c# (preferred) or ajax. 
I tried to call it from c# but class is not accessible there. So what can I do?

VB code look like this:

```
Partial Class PatientAppointmant_box
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
.
.
.
Public Sub foo()
`Dim define few adapters
'fille this and bind to datasource 
End Sub
```

I want to call this `foo()` from generic handler.

Comment: Is it VB.NET, or VB that you're trying to call?

Comment: Inside my web.config it says `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility, Version=10.0.0.0`, I do not know vb

Comment: @JohnWu yes it is forms application, I missed to mention it.

Comment: So do you have a web site that is ASP.NET web forms written in VB and written in c#? Or is the c# program a separate application?

Comment: I have added a generic handler in c#. Right now I solved the problem with location.reload() but you know frequent page load cause annoyance in user

Comment: I want to call vb sub in generic handler but I can not access the class there neither I can find any namespace.